# How do you set the box width in a plotly box in python?

Tags: python, plotly

I currently have the following;

```
y = time_h
time_box = Box(
    y=y,
    name='Time (hours)',
    boxmean=True,
    marker=Marker(color='green'),
    boxpoints='all',
    jitter=0.5,
    pointpos=-2.0
)
layout = Layout(
    title='Time Box',
)
fig = Figure(data=Data([time_box]), layout=layout)
plotly.image.save_as(fig, os.path.join(output_images, 'time_box.png'))
```

This renders the following graph:

[image]

The box is too wide and I haven't been able to find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also mess around with the `boxgap` (and `boxgroupgap` for when there are multiple boxes at different x locations, like here: https://plot.ly/python/box-plots/#Grouped-Box-Plot) property inside `Layout`. More details here: [Plotly Python Reference - Box Gap](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#Layout-boxgap)

Make sure that you have version 1.3.1 or higher.
`$ pip install plotly --upgrade`

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

data = Data([
    Box(
        y=[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21],
        boxpoints='all',
        jitter=0.3,
        pointpos=-1.8
    )
])

layout = Layout(
    boxgap=0.5
)

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='box-plot-with-gap')
```

https://plot.ly/~chris/3048
[image: Simple Plotly box-plot with group gap]

Some more examples:

`boxgap=0` and `boxgroupgap=0`:
[image: boxgap=0, boxgroupgap=0]

`boxgap=0.25` and `boxgroupgap=0`:
[image]

`boxgap=0` and `boxgroupgap=0.25`:
[image]

`boxgap=0.25` and `boxgroupgap=0.25`:
[image]

It's also helpful to play around with these parameters in the Workspace, where you can modify every parameter of the graphs: 
[image]

Comment: This works great for keeping Candlestick boxes together too. 
`fig = go.Figure(data)` `fig.update_layout(boxgap=0, boxgroupgap=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
layout = Layout(
    title='Time Box',
    width=500,
    height=500
)
```

This should create a 500x500 graph

See https://plot.ly/python/setting-graph-size/ for more info

Comment: I was thinking about changing the actual element in the graph, not the size of the whole graph, but this solution has worked well. Thanks.