# Changing the widths of plotly boxes and/or the space between them

Tags: r, plotly, width, boxplot, space

I have grouped data which I want to plot as a group of box plots using `R`'s `plotly` package, and control the width of the boxes and/or the space between theme.

Here are the data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(type = c(rep("t1", 1000), rep("t2", 1000), rep("t3", 1000), rep("t4", 1000), rep("t5", 1000), rep("t6", 1000)),
                 age = rep(c(rep("y", 500),rep("o", 500)), 6),
                 value = rep(c(runif(500, 5, 10), runif(500, 7.5, 12.5)), 6),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
df$age <- factor(df$age, levels = c("y", "o"), ordered = T)
```

Following `plotly`'s [tutorial](https://plotly.com/r/box-plots/) this is how I'm plotting it:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
plot_ly(x = df$type, y = df$value, name = df$age, color = df$type, type = 'box',showlegend = F) %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(title="Diversity"),boxmode='group')
```

Which gives:
[image]

Where the boxes come out too narrow and the space both between boxes of the same `type` as well as the space between the different `type`s are big.

Any idea how to change the box widths and/or the spaces?

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534247/how-do-you-set-the-box-width-in-a-plotly-box-in-python), in `python` the `boxgap` and `boxgroupgap` control these aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Analogous to the python version, layout parameters as being documented [here](https://plotly.com/r/reference/box/) can be changed as arguments of the function `layout`:

```
plot_ly(x = df$type, y = df$value, name = df$age, color = df$type,
  type = "box", showlegend = F) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "Diversity"),
   boxmode = "group", boxgap = 0, boxgroupgap = 0
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, even with setting both `boxgap` and `boxgroupgap` to 0, the boxes still come out too narrow. Any idea how to adjust the width of the boxes?

Comment: Must be something deeper in the implementation. This is everything we can do according to the documentation

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use a continuous x-axis. Here with ggplotly instead:

```
# convert factors to numbers
df$itype <- as.numeric (factor (df$type))
sc <- scale (unique (as.numeric (factor (df$age))))
df$iage <- sc[as.numeric (factor (df$age))] * .3

# plot
gg <- 
  ggplot (df, aes (x=itype+iage, y=value, color=type, group=itype+iage)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = levels (factor (df$type)), breaks = 1:length (levels (factor (df$type)))) +
  labs (x="", y="Diversity")


ggplotly (gg) %>%
  layout(boxgroupgap = 0, boxgap=0)
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov7fY.png)